# Status bar influence in presentViewController:animated:completion

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm having a problem that I don't really know why it is caused.

In my app I have a main view controller whose frame is (0, 0, 320, 480) (iphone4). In this controller I just present another view controller modally when an event happens. However, and though the view controller in fact occupies the whole screen, this view controller's view frame is (0, 20, 320, 480).

The problem seems to be in the status bar that makes that 20 to appear. However, the main view controller also let you see that status bar and that doesn't affect its frame. If I set the status bar to be hidden in the Info.plist, no problems appear here, but I don't want to do this. Do you know how to solve this?

Bye and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

keep the frame as (0, 20, 320, 460). if you want status bar on screen. Since default screen size is 480 but with status bar its 460. So modify your frame and apply.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put proper autosizing for your second view controllers view and subviews, so that they will remain on their places even if frame changes. Or, as @Rahul suggested keep your view's height 460. Good Luck!

Comment: But why is the frame changing if botch view controllers occupies the same space in the screen?

Comment: I don't know, provide some screenshots, so that we can explain you.